# How to process old Logs with Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to process 'old' log files on my local ELK stack (macOs), but I can't get Logstash to read my files.

```
{"eventid": "cowrie.direct-tcpip.data", "timestamp": "2016-07-10T03:00:17.713013Z", "format": "direct-tcp forward to %(dst_ip)s:%(dst_port)s with data %(data)s", "sensor": "sensor", "system": "says message", "src_ip": "8.8.8.8", "session": "session", "dst_port": 25, "dst_ip": "0.0.0.0", "message": "message'", "data": "data", "isError": 0}
```

When I input one line on STDIN, it works fine. ( But some of the lines are too big to de copy pasted as STDIN)

```
input {
       # this is the actual live log file to monitor
       file {
              path => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/ServerLogs/cowrie.json"
              start_position => beginning
              ignore_older => 0
              sincedb_path => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/ServerLogs/cowrie.sincedb"
              codec => json_lines
              sincedb_write_interval => 15
              discover_interval => 5
       }
       stdin{
       codec =>json_lines
       type => "cowrie"
       }

}

filter {
    if [type] == "cowrie" {

        json {
            source => message
        }

        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
        }

        if [src_ip]  {

            dns {
                reverse => [ "src_host", "src_ip" ]
                action => "append"
            }

            geoip {
                source => "src_ip"
                target => "geoip"
                database => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/logstash-2.3.3/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
                add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
                add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
            }

            geoip {
                source => "src_ip"
                database => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/logstash-2.3.3/vendor/geoip/GeoIPASNum.dat"
            }

            mutate {
                convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "cowrie" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts =>  ["localhost:9200"]
        }
        file {
            path => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/tmp/cowrie-logstash.log"
            codec => json
        }
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, read every Stack Overflow question, and nothing seems to work.

Is there any other method I can use ?

Comment: Try this : Start logstash and elasticsearch , open the log file you want use ,copy entire logs and paste it in the same file , save it. Let me know if this is working .

Comment: @rresol I have tried something similar that didn't work: I moved the old file and created a new one pasting everything from the old one in it.
But I'm not sure the programs were running simultaneously or if I re-oppened them afterwards.

Comment: Try it . And make sure the logstash and elasticsearch are running. I had similar problem but i figured out that when i was adding any new content to to the file it was being emitted as the event

Comment: Did you delete your sincedb files? Also - you realise that your file input never sets the type? That means that neither your filter nor output will get invoked. Add the same type info in the file that you have in the stdin and rerun. Your config is correct and should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
file {
          path => "/Users/Auyer/ELK/ServerLogs/cowrie.json"
          start_position => beginning
          sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
          codec => json_lines
          type => "cowrie"
   }
```

A few days back I had a similar problem. Setting `sincedb_path` to `/dev/null` fixed the problem.

Comment: The problem was that the "type" line was missing